Iptables which network interface am i using?
ip addr

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:bb:c1:a3:c6:aa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.88/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute enp5s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

For a rule like this, do i have to use:
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/8  -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j flood

or
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i enp5s0  -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j flood


What distro are you using? There's more than one way to set up networking. You should be using enp5s0, but its possible its set up elsewhere.

Hello, i'm using Debian.

Version's needed to. You might be using systemd's networking method or network manager. Makes it easier to look up

Hello, i'm using Debian 12.8 Bookworm
